# Javascript Alert box popup

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple question. I'm a beginner at Javascript. I was wondering what is the correct method to write a Javascript alert box?
Is it along the lines of {alert}?

Comment: `alert("Message");`  Did you try searching before posting your question?  Knowing as much as you do, it wouldn't be hard to find it.  A good query would be the title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert('whatever you want the alert to be");
```

should work! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Window alert() Method**

Display an alert box:

```
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
```

**Definition and Usage**

> The **alert()** method displays an alert box with a specified message and
>   an OK button.
>
> **An alert box is often used if you want to make sure information comes
>   through to the user.**
>
> **Note**: The alert box takes the focus away from the current window, and forces the browser to read the message. Do not overuse this
>   method, as it prevents the user from accessing other parts of the page
>   until the box is closed.

**Method    alert() Browser Support**

```
**Chrome** :Yes **IE**:Yes  **FireFox**:Yes **Safari**:Yes  **Opera**:Yes
```

**Syntax**

```
alert(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("Your alert text here");
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript `alert` is a function. All functions are commonly invoked in a simple way

**Function Syntax**

```
functionName(Arguments);
```

arguments are put in place of `Arguments` and are separated by commas.

**Alert Example**

so in this case, the function is `alert` and it accepts one argument, a String (text). So the syntax would be:

```
alert('My wonderful alert box!');
```

---

**More on Functions**

You can learn plenty about alerts [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert). If you wonder why it might say `window.alert` that's because `alert` is located under `window` (everything). To learn more about functions I recommend referencing [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).